# SSRS - export to PDF : columns split between two pages

Tags: pdf, ssrs-2008-r2

I need to export a report in PDF.

My report contains 2 tables that are too wide to fit on one page.

But the first table is splitted between pages in the middle of columns, and the second table is splitted on the separations of columns.

Maybe a screen cap could be useful :

[Tables are splitted differently](https://i.stack.imgur.com/htCJE.png)

As you can see, because of this, the columns of the two tables are not lined up to each other any more.

I think this happens because in the first table the first line is not divided into columns. But i'm not allowed to change this and i need to keep the two tables lined up.

Could you help me to fix this ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It looks like from your screenshot that the first header is actually all of the columns merged into 1 cell.  This should not cause any issues lining up with the second table.  Are the tables lined up when you view them in a web browser (before you export to PDF)?

Comment: Yes, in a web browser the tables are lined up.

Comment: Couple observations: First, exporting SSRS to pdf is often an imprecise endeavor.  I do a lot of it and it generally takes a good deal of tweaking in BIDS to get the exported pdf to look they way the customer needs it- to the point it will look very wrong in the web interface.  
Second, if you can't change the report, how are they expecting you to fix the issue?  I suppose you could put a matching 'first line' which is not divided into columns on the second table so they render the same if you can modify at least that part of things.